# How do I create an empty Nether and an empty End dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mcedit

I'm trying to create my own SkyBlock map for 1.14 Minecraft but I'm struggling. I am able to create an empty overworld map, but that's not the problem. **But how do I create an empty Nether and an empty end?** I often read MCEdit could do this, others wrote that MCEdit would work for stuff like that. **Do you guys have any hint or idea on how to accomplish this?**

Comment: So why not just download a world?

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a way without WorldEdit or are you asking how to do it with WorldEdit?

Answer (score 2):

Ilmango recently started a new 1.14 Skyblock series and provided an instructional video along with a full set of tools (links in the video description) to create the entirely empty world (including Nether and End) and adding some tweaks that allow to obtain/produce some resources that would otherwise be unavailable.

(The entire process is rather lengthy and convoluted never mind impossible to perform without the tools linked, so I see no point describing what's in the video here)

Comment: Can I change the files of my minecraft world to a void world? If yes, what would be the way without corrupting the files?

Answer (score 1):

A way that works if you don't need much space is the following procedure that uses the file system:

1. Create a new Void Overworld
2. Fly around, maybe with high chunk loading distance, generating as many chunks as you need.
3. Go to your world files where you want to create a void nether.
4. Replace the `region` files in `DIM-1` with the files from the Void World
5. Enter the nether.

Unlike [SF](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9440/sf)'s [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/351012/237000), my procedure has one advantage, but also on disadvantage, the ones being:

- No additional tools required.
- This does not generate a complete void nether, so you would have to manually add empty chunks.
- No guarantees regarding consistent biome information.

This process looks like this:

[image: Image showcase a void overworld]
[image: File System Depicted]
[image: Void Nether]

Answer (score -3):

You have to get something called the barrier block to put around the edges NOT ON THE BOTTOM for the bottom you can use a fill command to fill with air...
Good luck!

Comment: There is definitely a better way to do this other than to limit the player with barrier blocks.